# decrypt external hard drive mac os catalina

Tags: hard-drive, encryption

I've got a LaCie 2TB external  SSD drive that i would like to decrypt. I tried the method found online of right clicking the drive in finder however there is no option to decrypt the drive there, I tried using the "diskutil cs revert" command in terminal and that didn't work either. I also tried doing it using disk utility itself and the option to decrypt wasn't there either. I'm running macOS catalina 10.15.4

Answer (score 1):

What file system is your external drive?
I have an external APFS volume and there is the 'Decrypt' option in finder so I am guessing that feature is fs-dependent.

Comment: Mine is journaled, encrypted. I figured it out using a different set of terminal comands i found after doing more digging online. thanks!

Comment: @gaelen: Please share the answer to the problem